# Copy/Backup VirtualMachine when suspended - VMWare WorkStation 10

Tags: backup, vmware-workstation, openstack

Is there any method to backup/copy Virtual Machine to another location for the cause of safety **without powering-off**?, with suspended mode?

Actually I have `OpenStack`(a cloud computing OS) installed inside that and if I power-off and then power-on again, some of the `OpenStack`'s services won't run.

Comment: No; Your not using a version of VMWare products that do support doing this.

Comment: So what should I do to backup my that virtual machine?

Comment: One solution is to migrate to one of those VMWare products that supports what you want to do.

Comment: @Ramhound So which one supports that?